# How to typeset the house of an algebraic number?

Tags: math-mode, symbols

I would like to reproduce the following text

[image: inequality involving the house of an algebraic integer]

but I couldn't find the house symbol neither through Detexify nor by looking through the [Comprehensive LaTeX Symbol List](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/symbols/comprehensive/). I also tried combining vertical bars and overline like

```
\left\lvert\overline{ \alpha }\rvert\right
\overline{\left\lvert \alpha \rvert\right}
```

to less than desirable results.

Comment: I had never seen this notation, since now.

Comment: I'm rather new to it, too, @Sigur. It's used in a course I'm taking.

Comment: @A.P., off topic question: what is the definition of `\house{\alpha}`?

Comment: @Sigur: it is the maximum absolute value of the conjugates of `\alpha`.

Comment: @Sigur -- i've found a use of this "symbol" from 1985: *math of comp*, **45**:171, pp.243 ff., by david boyd.  it's referred to there as "maximum modulus", and it isn't in unicode.  as soon as i can get my workstation to launch my x-windows so that i can research my unicode contact info, i'll be submitting this for addition to the 2D00 "diacritics for use with math symbols" block.  (the name "house" appears to be rather newer; i have found a few other references using this construction, but "house" appears only post-2000.)

Comment: @Sigur -- i've heard back from my unicode contacts that a "cover" corresponding to this was requested earlier in the context of roman numerals, and rejected -- use markup, they say.  mathml has the concept "menclose" that would include this shape, but it isn't, in fact, covered in the list that otherwise looks like a pretty thorough documentation of the element.  i'll take this up with david carlisle when i get back to the office at the end of april.  (off to germany to enjoy dante's 25th anniversary celebration, and then some rustication.)

Answer (score 46, accepted):

There are some issues to consider:

### Line width

- The standard line width in TeX is `0.4pt`, it is hardcoded in TeX as `26214sp`.
- `\overline` uses a different line width. It is taken from font parameter 8 of math font family 3 in TeX.

  The standard math fonts (Computer Modern) are using `0.39998pt` in all font sizes. But it is scalable in other fonts, e.g. package `mathptmx` with `10pt` as class option:

  - `0.3999pt` in `\textfont` (`\textstyle`/`\displaystyle`)
  - `0.29591pt` in `\scriptfont` (`\scriptstyle`)
  - `0.23993pt` in `\scriptscriptfont` (`\scriptscriptstyle`)

### `\overline`

- TeX constructs a `\overline{...}` the following way with `θ` as line width (pseudo code):

  ```
  \vbox{
    \kern θ
    \hrule height θ
    \kern 3*θ
    \hbox{$...$}
  }
  ```

  Especially there is white space above the rule. This is useful, if the overlined symbol is put in the denominator of a fraction, for instance.
- TeX uses cramped math style for the math expression of `\overline`. This means, the superscripts are moved down a little, for a better visual appearance.

Thus `\overline` looks like a good choice for the "house" symbols. However, the vertical lines should use the same line width as used by `\overline`.

### Spacings

- TeX inserts 3 * θ (θ = line width of `\overline`) between the formula and the line in `\overline`. This cannot be easily changed without loosing cramped style. (AFAIK only LuaTeX can set cramped style explicitly.)
- Extra space is added above the line in `\overline`, see above.
- Usually symbols have side bearings, space at the left and right side of the symbol. The exact amount is usually not available in TeX. The example uses 2 * θ as horizontal space between the vertical lines and the formula. Also a horizontal space 1.5 * θ is put outside the vertical lines. Some kind of side bearings of the new symbol to avoid touching of housed math expressions.
- Since the OP wants longer lines (see [comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/169907/how-to-typeset-the-house-of-an-algebraic-number#comment391177_169909)), the example adds 2 * θ as additional depth. (3 * θ seems too large, because there is not a underline that needs some distance from the formula.)

The full example also takes into account the different math styles, thus macro `\house` respects the current math sizes.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathptmx}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\house}[1]{%
  \mathord{%
    \mathpalette\@house{#1}%
  }%
}
\newcommand*{\@house}[2]{%
  % #1: math style
  % #2: expression that gets the "house"
  % get the line width of `\overline' in the current math font size
  \dimen@=\fontdimen8 %
      \ifx#1\scriptscriptstyle\scriptscriptfont
      \else\ifx#1\scriptstyle\scriptfont
      \else\textfont\fi\fi
      3 %
  \sbox0{%
    $#1%
      \vrule width\dimen@\relax
      \overline{%
        \kern2\dimen@
        \begingroup % to keep changes of \dimen@ in #2 local
          #2%
        \endgroup
        \kern2\dimen@
      }%
      \vrule width\dimen@\relax
      \mathsurround=1.5\dimen@ % outside margin
    $%
  }%
  % TeX adds an empty space above `\overline', it needs to be
  % removed to get the correct height for the `\vrule's
  \ht0=\dimexpr\ht0-\dimen@\relax
  \dp0=\dimexpr\dp0+2\dimen@\relax
  \vbox{%
    \kern\dimen@ % reinsert previously removed space
    \copy0 %
  }%
}

\begin{document}
\[
  \textstyle % same size as \displaystyle
  \house{\alpha + \beta}
  \stackrel{\mbox{\tiny T}}{=}
  \house{\alpha} + \house{\beta}^n
\]
\[
  \scriptstyle
  \house{\alpha + \beta}
  \stackrel{\mbox{\tiny S}}{=}
  \house{\alpha} + \house{\beta}^n
\]
\[
  \scriptscriptstyle
  \house{\alpha + \beta}
  \stackrel{\mbox{\tiny SS}}{=}
  \house{\alpha} + \house{\beta}^n
\]
\[
  \def\x{\frac{\house{\alpha + \beta}}{\house{\alpha} + \house{\beta}}}
  \x, \frac{\x}{\x} 
\]
\[
  \underbrace{\overline{\alpha^2}, \house{\alpha^2}}_{\mbox{\tiny cramped}} \ne
  \overline{\mbox{$\alpha^2$}}, \house{\mbox{$\alpha^2$}}
\]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: Awesome! * epic music playing *

Comment: This is a great answer, thanks! One last question: would it be possible to add a little space to the (outer) sides of the symbol, so that e.g. `\house{\alpha}\house{\beta}` or `\house{\alpha}^n` do not look too cramped?

Comment: There is already some space (0.5 line width), I have increased it to 1.5 line width and added exponents in the test file.

Comment: Lovely! Does the space come from `\mathsurround=.5\dimen@`?

Comment: +1 just for the trick of adjusting the height and depth of the `\vrule`s by changing the height and depth of `\box0` *after* having built it—and with the rules already inside it!  But why `\copy0` and not simply `\box0`?  Am I missing something?  **Edit:** Perhaps because the contents of the box would be saved on the save stack anyway?

Comment: @GuM Because `\@house` with box construction and usage is called inside a group (`\mathord`), box register 0 is restored anyway to the state before `\house`, no matter, whether `\copy` or `\box` was used.

Answer (score 16):

Here is a plain TeX solution. The downside is, that `\everymath` is executed inside the "house". If you want every house to have the same height and depth, add a strut or a phantom inside it.

```
\nopagenumbers% for cropping
\def\house#1{{%
    \setbox0=\hbox{$#1$}
    \vrule height \dimexpr\ht0+1.4pt width .4pt depth \dp0\relax
    \vrule height \dimexpr\ht0+1.4pt width \dimexpr\wd0+2pt depth \dimexpr-\ht0-1pt\relax
    \llap{$#1$\kern1pt}
    \vrule height \dimexpr\ht0+1.4pt width .4pt depth \dp0\relax
}}


$\house{\alpha + \beta} \leq \house{\alpha} + \house{\beta}$
\medskip
$\house{\strut\alpha + \beta} \leq \house{\strut\alpha} + \house{\strut\beta}$
\bye
```

> [image]

Bonus question: Is there a plain TeX dimen, which holds the default linewidth of `.4pt`? I only know about `\p@=1pt` and `\z@=0pt`.

Comment: The default value of `0.4pt` for `\hrule` or `\vrule` is hardcoded in TeX as `26214sp` (= `0.4pt`). The line width for `\overline` depends on the fonts and are available in the font parameter `\fontdimen8\<math size>font3 `, e.g. `\fontdimen8\scriptfont3 ` in math style `\scriptstyle`. The CM fonts are using `0.39998pt` in all sizes (`text`, `script`, `scriptscript`. The line width of `\overline` in fonts by package `mathptmx` gets smaller with smaller sizes (`0.3999pt`/`\textstyle`, `0.29591pt`/`\scriptstyle`, and `0.23993pt`/`\scriptscriptstyle`; in all cases with `10pt` as class option).

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek Thank you very much for that clarification!

Comment: Is there a way to increase the length of the vertical bars, so that they are slightly longer than the argument?

Comment: @A.P. Well, the vertical bar is longer than the argument. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: More precisely: is it possible to make the vertical bars protrude slightly from under the argument?

Comment: @A.P. Replace `\dp0` with `\dimexpr\dp0+.5pt`. Of course you can adjust the `.5pt` to your liking.

Answer (score 10):

With the horizontal bar slightly protruding:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{array}

\newcommand\house[1]{%
  \begingroup\setlength\arraycolsep{0pt}
  \begin{array}[t]{@{\mkern1mu}c@{}|c|@{}c@{\mkern1mu}}
  \firsthline
  &\;#1\;{}&
  \end{array}
  \endgroup
}


\begin{document}

$\house{\alpha + \beta} \leq \house{\alpha} + \house{\beta}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

The protrusion can be controlled by increasing the amount given with `\mkern`; this is with `\mkern2mu`

[image]

As barbara beeton notes in a comment, the bar shouldn't protrude; for this just remove the `\mkern` instruction:

```
\newcommand\house[1]{%
  \begingroup\setlength\arraycolsep{0pt}
  \begin{array}[t]{@{}c@{}|c|@{}c@{}}
  \firsthline
  &\;#1\;{}&
  \end{array}
  \endgroup
}
```

[image]

Comment: nope, don't want the horizontal bar protruding.  here's a reference "in the literature": [david w. boyd, "the maximal modulus of an algebraic integer", math. of comp., 45:171 (1985), pp.243-249](http://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1985-45-171/S0025-5718-1985-0790657-8/S0025-5718-1985-0790657-8.pdf).  that one wasn't done with tex; it was most likely composed with the sti system, and clearly was "patched together" (the top edge of the box doesn't always meet the verticals).  but it's the earliest reference i've found that's readily accessible.

Answer (score 4):

An implementation with `tikz`, shamefully adapted from [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/117504/27664)

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\newcommand{\house}[1]{%
  \tikz[baseline]{\node[anchor=base,inner sep=0.3ex](mynode){\ensuremath{#1}};
  \draw(mynode.south west)--(mynode.north west)--(mynode.north east)--(mynode.south east);
  \path[use as bounding box]($(mynode.south west)+(-0.3ex,-0.3ex)$)rectangle($(mynode.north east)+(0.3ex,0.3ex)$);}
}

\begin{document}
  $\house{\alpha+\beta}\leq\house{\alpha}+\house{\beta}$
\end{document}
```

---

[image: compiled output]

Answer (score 4):

Never seen it either. However, here is a way of doing things: put everything into an array, with `hhline` to have a clean connection of vertical and horizontal lines. I define a normal and a bold version I don'tknow how to declare it, so as to have only one command for both versions):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{hhline, bm}
 \newcommand\house[1]{\mkern2mu\begin{array}{|@{\:}c@{\:}|}\hhline{|-|}#1\end{array}\mkern1mu}
 \newcommand\boldhouse[1]{\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{0.6pt}\mathversion{bold}%
 \mkern2mu\begin{array}{|@{\:}c@{\: }|}\hhline{|-|}#1\end{array}\mkern1mu}%

\begin{document}

 $ \house{α + β} \leq \house{α} + \house{β}$\\

 $\mathversion{bold} \boldhouse{α + β} \leq \boldhouse{α} + \boldhouse{β} $

\end{document}
```

The result, in my opinion, is better than the OP's image (same height for all symbols):

[image]
There should remain to define a bold version.

Answer (score 0):

```
\newcommand{\house}[1]{
  \setbox0=\hbox{$#1$}
  \rule{.4pt}{\dimexpr\ht0 + 1.6pt}
  \overline{\mkern+1mu
    #1
  \mkern+1mu}
  \rule{.4pt}{\dimexpr\ht0 + 1.6pt}
}
```